# Google Script Conditional Formatting with multiple conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am writing a script to conditionally format my spreadsheet, but I do not know how to create multiple conditions. I have tried several edits to fix my problem, which is that when I run this function, every blank cell in the column will turn red, or every cell that meets the conditions of formula2 will turn red. I want only the cells that both meet formula2 conditions and are blank to turn red.

When I use the notation .whenCellEmpty().whenFormulaSatisfied(formula2)...
All of the cells that meet formula2 conditions turn red, even if they are not blank.

When I use the notation .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula2).whenCellEmpty()...
All of the blank cells turn red, even when they don't meet formula2 conditions.

Is there a way to write both of these conditions into the same rule?

```
var range2a = sheet.getRange(3, 16, sheet.getLastRow()-2, 1);
var range2b = sheet.getRange(3, 17, sheet.getLastRow()-2, 1);
var formula2 = '=OR(D3:D="Sale Escrow", D3:D="Sold", D3:D="Subsequent 
       Issue")';
var rule2a = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellEmpty().whenFormulaSatisfied(formula2)
    .setBackground("#FF0000")
    .setRanges([range2a])
    .build();
var rules2a = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules2a.push(rule2a);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules2a);


var rule2b = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellEmpty()
    .setBackground("#FF0000")
    .setRanges([range2b])
    .build();
var rules2b = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules2b.push(rule2b);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules2b);
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't explicitly stated in the Apps Script documentation for [`ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#), but the `when____` methods serve as one-off shortcuts that define when the rule activates, by creating a [`BooleanCondition`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/boolean-condition.html) for it.

The limitation is, however, noted in the `BooleanCondition` documentation:

> Each conditional format rule may contain a single boolean condition. The boolean condition itself contains a boolean criteria (with values) and formatting settings. The criteria is evaluated against the content of a cell resulting in either a `true` or `false` value. If the criteria evaluates to `true`, the condition's formatting settings are applied to the cell.

Thus, the various `when____` methods do not combine with other `when___` methods: whichever is used last on a rule, is the one that is active for that rule, as it has replaced the previous criteria that rule was using.

Note that the `BooleanCondition` is a read-only class in Apps Script - there are no methods available to the programmer to manually construct or modify a `BooleanCondition`. If one could create or modify a `BooleanCondition`, one could in theory create the evaluable boolean condition that evaluates a cell based on multiple criteria.

For now, however, the closest approach is with the `whenFormulaSatisfied` method, as your formula can be as complex as you desire, and perform the same calculations you would be doing if you could manually edit the `BooleanCondition`.

> `=OR(D1="A", D1="B", D1="C")*NOT(A1="")`

The multiplication operator is the equivalent of a Boolean `AND`, while addition would be the equivalent of a Boolean `OR`.